# linux inter driver communication

Tags: c, linux, driver, linux-device-driver

on a raspberry pi I want to be able to use a rotary encoder as volume control.
the best way I can see to do that would be using the rotary_encoder module to read the encoder, set it up as a relative axis (so would get +1 or -1 events) and then make a driver to interpret that to create volume up or volume down keypresses.

however I'm struggling to get my head around interrupts and drivers, so my driver would have to register itself as able to provide EV_KEY events, which I think I've got handled, but I'm unsure how I can catch and act on events from the other driver?

I figured I would have to poll the /dev/input/event object created by the other driver, but I can't seem to find a guide on how to do this?

is this the best way to go? is there a way i can actually catch interrupts created by the other driver feeding events into the input system?

Comment: All drivers run in kernel mode, in the same address space. If you are writing both drivers, then you can call function on one module from the other module, using `EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(...)` or similar.

Comment: @rodrigo I'm trying to make use of an existing driver, i'd rather not change it if i can avoid it. I could always copy the bits i want into my driver but i'd rather not duplicate any functionality if i can help it.

Comment: I see... take a look at `int input_register_handler(struct input_handler *handler)` function. Maybe it does what you need.

Comment: that looks like it would do what i want, but struggling to find good examples on how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to receive input events from an unrelated module. But you cannot read `/dev/input/event*` from kernel space, so you have to options:

1. Write a user mode daemon that reads the `/dev/input/event*` and forwards to your driver, maybe with a char device or a sysfs parameter.
2. Hook on the input driver events from your driver.

Option 1 should be straightforward. I'll elaborate on option 2.

To hook an input device from kernel you use function `input_register_handler()` from your module init function (and `input_unregister_handler()`  from your exit function, of course).

This function takes a `struct input_handler` as argument, it has a lot of members, but you probably only need to fill `name`, `id_table`, `connect`, `disconnect` and `event`.

Then, in your `connect` callback you call `input_register_handle()` (note the `handle` vs `handler` names) and `input_open_device()` and you will get input events in your `event` callback.

Of course, do not forget to undo that work in your `disconnect` callback.

There are several instances of this API usage in the kernel, but by far the easier one to read is the `evbug` driver: it just dumps all input events into the kernel log.

Comment: this is exactly the kind of example i was looking for, thank you!

Comment: is there any docs you are aware of that would help me figure out how to filter events to only the device i'm interested in? id_table looks like a start but i can't find any documentation on valid values?

Comment: @JamesKent: Yes, `id_table` should be enough for most cases, and the `filter` callback for advanced ones. If you want a particular device, you can just specify `bustype`, `vendor` and `product`. If you want any device of a particular kind or any device that has some `EV_BTN`... then you fill the other members. Ah, do no forget the `flags` to tell what members to use (`INPUT_DEVICE_ID_MATCH_BUS | INPUT_DEVICE_ID_MATCH_VENDOR | INPUT_DEVICE_ID_MATCH_PRODUCT`).